# How to measure public interest in your github project?

Tags: github

I've started a new project on github, and I wonder if there is a way to see if anyone downloads the code at all. I would imagine if anyone does then it would be a clone request, but I can't find a way to access that count. Absent forking and feature requests, I can't tell if there is any interest in project, and I have no idea if it's even worth keeping it on github at all. Anyone knows what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this information is available.

Most of the interest metrics I've seen at GitHub revolve around the number of forks and stars a repository has. Of course, the number of commits and contributors are also useful.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD.:** GitHub released traffic analytics https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics

There is a service that measures amount of traffic - https://bitdeli.com/ , of course it's not perfect, but might give you a picture.

You just need to add their embed code (image) in readme, take a look at example on my [Magnific Popup repository](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup)  (at the bottom of page).